# WPF Margin не изменяется в DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, grid, margin

Не изменяется именно марджин, другое ( например background) работает как надо.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" >
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ChangeMargin, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness Left="-20" Right="-320.8"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="black">

                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <Button  x:Name="ChangeMargin" BorderThickness="0"   Background="White" Canvas.Left="178" Canvas.Top="262" Height="25"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: А почему так "развернуто" задаете значение? Просто `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="200 0 0 0">`, не? А по поводу "не изменяет", попробуйте задать дефолтное значение, перед триггерами `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0">`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так сработало, спасибо! Но марджин изменяется только в тот момент когда я удерживаю кнопку. Как только отпускаю, он возвращается на место. Не знаете, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Я проверил ваш код из вопроса, все там работает, проблема в том, что у вас минусовые значения, которые идут за края (что очень странно). А по поводу `Как только отпускаю` - Ну так вы привязываете к чему? `Path=IsPressed`, какое тогда вы поведение от него еще ожидаете? Привязывайте к чему либо еще, можете сделать свойство для этого отдельное.